# Placing imageviews in a circular manner by placing a center in android

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-imageview

I want to implement **drag and drop** in `android 4.1`, for that i want to place my icons image views in circular manner around a center point. **(with image view i can implement drag and drop perfectly, with bitmap its somewhat complex)**

I tried with bitmaps and paint but it is not as smooth, as we can get in android 4.1.

`Is there any method or way in android 4.1 by which i can place the imageviews in circular manner by giving the radius of the circle and number of sections it will get divide, its like a math question ?`

Take a look at this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) for drag and drop.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented by using **Math** in android.

I am sharing a part of my code:

```
double xOffset = currentRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(d));
double yOffset = currentRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(d));
```

Hope it will be helpful to u. Please follow [here](http://math.stackexchange.com) to learn more.